# SQLAlchemy: list of objects, preserve reference if they're deleted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement a user-facing PreviewList of Articles, which will keep its size even if an `Article` is deleted. So if the list has four objects `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and one is deleted, I want it to contain `[1, 2, None, 4]`.

I'm using a relationship with a `secondary` table. Currently, deleting either `Article` or `PreviewList` will delete the row in that table. I've experimented with cascade options, but they seem to affect the related items directly, not the contents of the `secondary` table.

The snippet below tests for the desired behaviour: deleting an `Article` should preserve the row in `ArticlePreviewListAssociation`, but deleting a `PreviewList` should delete it (and not the `Article`).

In the code below, deleting the `Article` will preserve the `ArticlePreviewListAssociation`, but `pl.articles` does not treat that as a list entry.

```
from db import DbSession, Base, init_db
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

session = DbSession()


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)


class PreviewList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'preview_lists'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    articles = relationship('Article', secondary='associations')


class ArticlePreviewListAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'associations'
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('articles.id'), nullable=True)
    previewlist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('preview_lists.id'), primary_key=True)

    article = relationship('Article')
    preview_list = relationship('PreviewList')


init_db()

print(f"Creating test data")
a = Article(title="StackOverflow: 'Foo' not setting 'Bar'?")
pl = PreviewList(articles=[a])
session.add(a)
session.add(pl)
session.commit()

print(f"ArticlePreviewListAssociations: {session.query(ArticlePreviewListAssociation).all()}")

print(f"Deleting PreviewList")
session.delete(pl)
associations = session.query(ArticlePreviewListAssociation).all()
print(f"ArticlePreviewListAssociations: should be empty: {associations}")
if len(associations) > 0:
    print("FAIL")

print("Reverting transaction")
session.rollback()

print("Deleting article")
session.delete(a)
articles_in_list = pl.articles
associations = session.query(ArticlePreviewListAssociation).all()
print(f"ArticlePreviewListAssociations: should not be empty: {associations}")
if len(associations) == 0:
    print("FAIL")
print(f"Articles in PreviewList: should not be empty: {articles_in_list}")
if len(articles_in_list) == 0:
    print("FAIL")
# desired outcome: pl.articles should be [None], not []

print("Reverting transaction")
session.rollback()
```

This may come down to "How can you make a many-to-many relationship where `pk_A == 1 and pk_B == NULL` include the `None` in A's list?"

Comment: What do you need to preserve this for? Do you just need to know the total number of articles, including deleted articles? Depending on your goal there may be much simpler solutions to this

Comment: It seems you expect to preserve order. As it is there seems to be insufficient information in your relations to do that.

Comment: Good point about order - yes, it's an eventual goal, I hadn't considered that it's a requirement here already. Will need to look more closely into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given examples would seem to assume that the order of related articles is preserved, even upon deletion. There are multiple approaches to that, for example the [Ordering List](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) extension, but it is easier to first solve the problem of preserving associations to deleted articles. This seems like a use case for an [association object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) and [proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html).

The `Article` class gets a new relationship so that deletions cascade in a session. The default [ORM-level cascading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html) behavior is to set the foreign key to NULL, but if the related association object is not loaded, we want to let the DB do it, so `passive_deletes=True` is used:

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)

    previewlist_associations = relationship(
        'ArticlePreviewListAssociation', back_populates='article',
        passive_deletes=True)
```

Instead of a many to many relationship `PreviewList` uses the association object pattern, along with an association proxy that replaces the many to many relationship. This time the cascades are a bit different, since the association object should be deleted, if the parent `PreviewList` is deleted:

```
class PreviewList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'preview_lists'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    article_associations = relationship(
        'ArticlePreviewListAssociation', back_populates='preview_list',
        cascade='all, delete-orphan', passive_deletes=True)

    articles = association_proxy(
        'article_associations', 'article',
        creator=lambda a: ArticlePreviewListAssociation(article=a))
```

Originally the association object used `previewlist_id` as the primary key, but then a `PreviewList` could contain a single `Article` only. A surrogate key solves that. The foreign key configurations include the DB level cascades. These are the reason for using passive deletes:

```
class ArticlePreviewListAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'associations'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    article_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('articles.id', ondelete='SET NULL'))
    previewlist_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('preview_lists.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        nullable=False)

    # Using a unique constraint on a nullable column is a bit ugly, but
    # at least this prevents inserting an Article multiple times to a
    # PreviewList.
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(article_id, previewlist_id), )

    article = relationship(
        'Article', back_populates='previewlist_associations')
    preview_list = relationship(
        'PreviewList', back_populates='article_associations')
```

With these changes in place no "FAIL" is printed.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Think I've got my head around association & proxies now. I'll try to merge this understanding with an ordering list for it to 'make sense' in my scenario.